# The file size exceeds configured limit (2,44 MB). Code insight features are not available

Tags: json, android-studio, filesize

Можно ли как то расширить размер формата Json B android studio?
Как пишется в программе android studio максимальный вес файла 2.44 МБ как сделать чтобы хотя бы на 1 мб больше можно было использовать этот файл. 
Как увеличить размер файла ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сжать его не вариант? я вижу вы на отступы не скупитесь)

Comment: @Павел _Игоревич я уже писал по этому поводу [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/881203/json-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) но не думаю что это сильно сократит размер файла

Comment: Спасибо буду сжимать, может подскажете какую-то программу которая сжимает json файлы?

Comment: Честно говоря, не доводилось сталкиваться с таким, но я думаю, что тут подойдет даже самый простой GULP на котором нужен один покет и небольшой скрипт, хотя снова-же не скажу точно сжимает он json или нет, но я уверен, что In the Internet вы сможете найти уйму решений данного вопроса)

Comment: максимальны вес к котором я смог сжать это c 2.6 до 2.2 мб с помощью [этого сайта](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Меню *Help* > *Edit Custom Properties*, добавить/изменить

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=скоканадо
```

Comment: память в битах или байтах?

Comment: Килобайты, вроде.