# Как решить проблему со скрытыми символами?

Tags: python, json, requests

В общем, работал я с json файлом, размером, больший, чем 2.56 МБ, у меня выдаёт ошибку в самом json'е:

The file size (6,91 MB) exceeds the configured limit (2,56 MB). Code insight features are not available.

После этого в json'е появляется вот такая штука:

```
"city_name": "�������"
```

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, помогите, пожалуйста, исправить

Comment: А кто и где вам это пишет? Может это про вот это? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/921828/260769

Comment: с кодировкой беда.

Comment: Да, пишет в самом json'e, как в этом вопросе

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Внутри `json` эта фраза находится с ошибкой? Покажите весь `json` тогда. Или это среда разработки какая-то ругается? Откуда вы берёте этот `json`, при чём тут `requests`? Покажите какой-нибудь код ещё, относящийся к вопросу. А "такая штука" - это да, это проблемы с кодировкой, но это уже второй вопрос. Нужно разбираться с кодировками.